# Ideal as a projective module

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am sorry, this may not be a good question here. I am looking a good reference about when the ideal $I$ of a given commutative ring $R$ (local or may not be local) with identity is a projective module.

Comment: "I am sorry, this may not be a good question here" Quite the contrary: this is a very good question! +1

Answer (score 11):

Here are some partial results if you strengthen the hypotheses on the ring:

*Definition*: Let $R$ be a domain, $Q=\operatorname{Frac}(R)$. An ideal $I$ is *invertible* if there are elements $a_1,\dots,a_n\in I$ and $q_1,\dots,q_n \in Q$ such that $q_iI\subset R$ for all $i$, and $1=\sum_{i=1}^n q_ia_i$.

**Theorem**: If $R$ is a domain, then a nonzero ideal $I$ is projective iff it is invertible.

If we move from domains to UFD's, then:

**Theorem**: If $R$ is a UFD, then a nonzero ideal $I$ is projective iff it is principal.

A reference for the above theorems is Rotman's "An Introduction to Homological Algebra", 2nd. edition, pp. 167-168.

Comment: See also [Dedekind domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain) and [hereditary rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_ring) for (commutative) rings having the property that *all* ideals are projective.

Comment: @Rajnish: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

For rings in general (with identity), the ring is called *right hereditary* if all right ideals are projective, and right semihereditary if all finitely generated right ideals are projective. There are a lot of other interesting equivalences and properties that these rings have, which you can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_ring).

A commutative hereditary domain is the same thing as a Dedekind domain, and a commutative semihereditary domain is the same thing as a Prüfer domain.

For examples that aren't domains (usually), [semisimple rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_ring#Semisimple_rings) are hereditary (on both sides) and [von Neumann regular rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring) are semihereditary (on both sides).